# Is it possible to use the "component" statement to implement an ngModel $parsers/ $formatters directive?

Tags: angularjs

I am reading the angularJs 1.5.7 documents, 
Binding select to a non-string value via ngModel parsing / formatting
https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/select

At the end of the document, there is an example of ngModel $parsers driective.

```
angular.module('nonStringSelect', [])
.run(function($rootScope) {
  $rootScope.model = { id: 2 };
})
.directive('convertToNumber', function() {
  return {
    require: 'ngModel',
    link: function(scope, element, attrs, ngModel) {
      ngModel.$parsers.push(function(val) {
        return parseInt(val, 10);
      });
      ngModel.$formatters.push(function(val) {
        return '' + val;
      });
    }
  };
});
```

I wonder if it's possible to use "component" statement to implement this directive.

```
appModule.component('converttoNumber', {
    controller: function(){
        ????
    }
})
```

Thanks.